# float:left CSS property breaking styling?

Tags: html, css

Why is `float:left` CSS property breaking styling?

```
<div id="application_header">
  <div>logo</div>
  <div><h5>tagline</h5></div>
</div>
```

`#application_header > div` is preventing `#application_header` background property from being applied because of: `float:left`?

```
.clear  { clear:both; }
.push   { clear: both; height: 20px;}

#application_header { display:block; background-color: #000; }
    #application_header > div { float: left; }
```

`#application_header` only accepts `background-color: #000;` property if `float:left` is removed... Explanation please...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div#application_header has no height because the elements contained within it are floated.

I made a fiddle that demonstrates adding a height to the div:

```
div#application_header { 
    height: 100px; 
    display:block; 
    background-color: #000; 
    color: #fff 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YGkw7/

Rather than floating your elements you could set them to inline-block

http://jsfiddle.net/YGkw7/2/

Answer (score 0):

The reason your background color is not showing up, is because the #application_header collapses to zero height and width as it only contains floating child elements. You'll want to look into a clear fix solution to have your parent div wrap around the floating child elements.

You can find more info on clear fix solutions at [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)